# I am looking to re-write a specific URl with php

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am using a PHP script to change my download link to "http://mydomain.com/get.php?download/" however I am looking to further change this to only show "/get.php?download/ or something more specific like "?php" on my web page where the button holds the link.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$path = 'folder/blank.file/';
$mm_type="application/octet-stream";
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

readfile($path); //output

exit();

?>
```

How is this possible? Thanks for your help!

Edit: Am using lighttpd and invision power board.

Comment: This link would be helpful: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I am using lighttpd and IPB.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if you already have made this (its an old question )...
but i have something that may help.

to rewrite, in IPB you can change the core files ... take a look in here:

{forum-root}/admin/applications_addon/ips/downloads/extensions/furlTemplates.php

in "idmdodownload" take a look in this row:

```
'out' => array( '/app=downloads(&amp;|&)module=display(&amp;|&)section=download(&amp;|&)do=do_download(&amp;|&)id=(.+?)(&|$)/i', 'files/download/$5-#{__title__}/$6' ),
```

you can rewrite that and i think you can get what you want ...

take a look at ->[my post about rewriting in IPB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348662/static-url-rewriting-the-subdir/19460756#19460756)