# static URL Rewriting the subdir

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ipb

i already shearch, and i never found this that i am asking, soo i want to know if it is even possible... or not ...

- I am testing this in IPB.Board 3.4.5, with the app IP.Downloads.
- I have this static url in my site that users can acess to download one file:

> mysite.com/**files/file**/2-filename.txt

The original dynamic url is something like:

> .../?app=downloads&showfile=2

The change of the url is made by that app (IP.Downloads)...

- i want to change it to url:

> mysite.com/**text**/2-filename.txt

so when the user insert in browser

1 mysite.com/text/2-filename.txt

- they see the file

2 mysite.com/files/file/2-filename.txt

- they are rewrite to   mysite.com/text/2-filename.txt

  - and see the file.

How can i do that? change from ( /files/file/ ) to ( /text/ ) ...
that can be made by .htaccess or i have to change the app files? or is impossible?

---

::UPDATE::

I have done it!  without .htaccess , i change the core files that rewrite the url...

see the Answer  below ...

---

*Thanks for any help.*

Comment: Shouldn't `mysite.com/files/file/1-name.txt` have been redirected to `mysite.com/text/1-name.txt`? Is `/1-test/` in your update a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it by changing the core files ... it is more simple for me, so i use this way.
thanks @ravi-thapliyal for trying to help making this by .htaccess, but i prefer this way ...

First  open this file:

{forum-root}/admin/applications_addon/ips/downloads/extensions

1. Edit this code ['*idmshowfile*'] in the $_SEOTEMPLATES = array

   - This will tell the server that when the user go to (myserver.com/text/) they want to see the file...
   - > 'idmshowfile' => array(
     >
     > ```
     >    'app'          => 'downloads',
     >
     >    'allowRedirect' => 1,
     >
     >    'out'          => array( '/app=downloads(&amp;|&)showfile=(.+?)(&|$)/i', 'text/$2-#{__title__}/$3' ),
     >
     >    'in'           => array( 
     >
     >        'regex'        => "#/text/(\d+?)-#i",
     >
     >        'matches'  => array( 
     >
     >            array( 'app'       , 'downloads' ),
     >
     >            array( 'showfile'  , '$1' ))
     >
     >            ) 
     >
     >    ),
     > ```
2. And add this code to $_SEOTEMPLATES = array, in any position ...

   - this will tell to server that if the user go to (myserver.com/files/file/) they will be rewrite the url (myserver.com/text/) , and see the file.
   - > 'idmshowfile2' => array(
     >
     > ```
     >    'app'          => 'downloads',
     >
     >    'allowRedirect' => 1,
     >
     >    'out'          => array( '/app=downloads(&amp;|&)showfile=(.+?)(&|$)/i', 'text/$2-#{__title__}/$3' ),
     >
     >    'in'           => array( 
     >
     >        'regex'        => "#/files/file/(\d+?)-#i",
     >
     >        'matches'  => array( 
     >
     >            array( 'app'       , 'downloads' ),
     >
     >            array( 'showfile'  , '$1' ))
     >
     >            ) 
     >
     >    ),
     > ```

You can add as many rewrites as you want to the Forum, and create nice and friendly SEO URL.

Of course i know that this file can be overwrite in future updates of the app, soo i will make backup, and if possibel create an hook or app to make this (... if possibel).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+files/file/([^?\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /text/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+text/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /files/file/%1
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but that dont work ...
i try to place that in my .htaccess file , but the url keep coming with the "/files/file/" instead the "/text/"
i think is because the system itself makes rewrite soo using the .htacess is not working ...
PS: i even set delete my "index.php" Rewrite to test your code , but it dont make the change ...

Comment: Does using `/text/..` directly work for you now? I get it. You need existing `/files/file/..` urls to get displayed as `/text/..` as well. Correct?

Comment: ...before your update...
uhm .. i forgot to say that, i will update my question,
I need existing /file/file/.. urls to get displayed as /text/ in user browser...

I tested now and if i input: "http://mysite.com/text/2-filename"
the page reamins in "http://mysite.com/text/2-filename" and return 404 error ..
...
i will check with the update and give the feedback ...

Comment: it still not making the Rewrite...
for test only if i insert "http://mysite.com/text/2-filename"
with your code the browser should show "http://mysite.com/text/2-filename" or "http://mysite.com/files/file/2-filename"??
because in my browser it still http://mysite.com/text/2-filename

Comment: Ah, mate I'm getting confused. In your first comment you said `but the url keep coming with the "/files/file/" instead the "/text/"` so I kept it `/text` now; while internally the server would resolve it as `/files/file`. Is this not what you want?

Comment: yeah, i want that the server internally  get "/files/file/" , but the user in the borswer get "/text/" ...

but i dont know if the .htacess is working with ipb ... because that i asked if is possibel or not with this type os system ..

Comment: Does IPB have any rules of its own in `htaccess`? I'm updating the answer to rewrite `/text` to the final `app=downloads` URL. Try that too. By the way, are you sure the final URL isn't `/?app=downloads&showfile=2`. It's unusual to have `key=value` as the target filename.

Comment: yes it have. i put the code in the question .. because its a bit big for this coment space ...
even with that last chances it dont rewrite the url ...
i made a test , and if i change your code , i can make the "text" rewrite to "files/file" .. but is not what i want, i still cant get the rewrite from "files/file" to "text"

Comment: Okay, place my rules before the IPB's `.htaccess` code. And, remove `[L]` from the second rule. Take a look at my update. Removing `[L]` would let IPB rules process `/files/file/` now.

Comment: If you still face problems please make an update to your question with the actual url entered, what you're getting redirected to and what it should have.

Comment: i will try to make this tomorow , i dont have more time today, thanks for the help.